# Defining the branch of $z^{1/n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $Log_{\gamma}(z) :=  Log|z| + iarg_{\gamma}(z)$, where $arg_{\gamma}(z)$ is the angle of $z$ as lying on$ [\gamma, \gamma + 2\pi)$, how can I similarly define $z^{1/n}$?

Comment: You should be able to define both $\log z$ and $z^{1/n}$ unambiguously, as analytic functions, on any simply connected domain not containing $0$. ( Your choice, your definition. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$z^{1/n} = \exp\big(\tfrac 1n \log z\big) = \exp\big(\tfrac 1n (\log|z| + i\arg(z))\big).$$
In other words, $z^{\frac 1n}$ is multivalued in general.